# Referencing Silverlight Class Library to MVC Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, silverlight

I have an existing working Silverlight application. I have a complicated method in one of the XAML.cs file which I am trying to re use. 
I want to call that method from an MVC application. I gave a try by referencing the silverlight class library to my mvc application to check whether it might work but ended up with getting exceptions(there were some UI elements declared in the xaml.cs class) while instantiating object of that class. Can anyone tell me an approach on how to do this in a better way. I am thinking about exposing the methods through services, however I want to know regarding better possibilities.

Comment: Well...if the code you want to re-use is generic enough that you actually find use for it without re-using the whole view...the best advice would be to pull it into a separate class. Post your code if you struggle with pulling it out of its current place.

Answer (score 0):

Xaml files (including their cs code-behind) should ideally only have code for dealing with user interface. This is a good example of why mixing UI with other logic leads to pain.

If the method in the xaml.cs is useful enough to be called from an external MVC application I'd say that it shouldn't be in the code-behind: it needs to live elsewhere and be called by the code-behind. It can then also be called by the MVC application.

tl;dr

1) Extract the method in question into a separate utility class

2) Call that class method from your code behind

3) Call that class method from your MVC application

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse XAML code in ASP.NET MVC application.

Bat you can extract server side logic code from Silverlight application and reuse it on ASP.NET MVC. It shouldn't be a complex issue if you Silverlight code is good designed.

In this case, you have to reimplement client side functionality only - replace C#\XAML with HTML\JS\CSS.

Also, you will be able to use extracted code in both Silverlight and ASP.NET MVC applications with Portable Class Library. Check out next articles how to use it:

- [Cross-Platform Development with the Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Using Portable Class Library with Model-View-View Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh563947(v=vs.110).aspx)